# Filter on columns using one pipe with array of values angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to filter an array of object with multiple array string values.

below is my array object is like

```
[{
    "name": "FULLY MAINTAINED MARUTI SUZUKI SWIFT VDI 2008",
    "model": "Swift"
}, {
    "name": "maruti suzuki test",
    "model": "Swift Desire"
}, {
    "name": "maruti suzuki test2",
    "model": "Alto"
}, {
    "name": "maruti suzuki swift desire for sale1",
    "model": "Zen"
}, {
    "name": "maruti suzuki test",
    "model": "Alto"
}, {
    "name": "maruti suzuki test",
    "model": "Zen"
}]
```

I am filtering this array of objects (above) with an array of strings (below)

```
this.filterData.model=["Swift","Zen"]
```

it has has to be display with all Swift and Zen models.
I have do with single value how to find with array of values.

Added a plunker link
[stackblitz Editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdzi8d?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this in your stackblitz it's not in edit mode :(.

Here is the code I added and extra variable on the component scope `this.filteredData:any[] = [];`

```
this.filterData.model=["Swift", "zen"];

 for(let i = 0; i < this.filterData.model.length; i++){
   let products = this.products.filter((product: any) =>
   product.model.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterData.model[i].toLowerCase()) === 0);
   for(let j = 0; j < products.length; j++){
      this.filteredData.push(products[j]);
   }
 }
 console.log(this.filteredData);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is just change this line from `filter.pipe.ts`

```
.find(key => item[key] !== filter[key]); // this was for string comparison
```

To :

```
.find(key => filter[key].indexOf(item[key]) == -1); // this is how you can do that with array
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-array)

Comment: if we add an another string to array it is not updating

Comment: I Used @Swoox logic in pipe its worked for me,.. thank you for your efforts.